# Quasar Firebase Initialization issue

Tags: firebase, quasar-framework

I'm currently following this guide https://dev.to/quasar/to-the-stars-with-quasar-firebase-user-profile-319l to implement authentication with firebase on my application.

The problem I've encountered is related to the Firebase API_KEY not being valid. I've followed all the steps in the guide regarding registering the app and adding the config data to the environment variable.

I'm still getting a Quasar boot error and a Firebase error message stating I have an invalid key. This is described at the end of the first part of the tutorial.

In the tutorial, there is also an explanation as to why this might be occurring "The Firebase API key doesn't get validated until an authentication method is executed." although I cannot grasp how to execute an authentication method.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found my mistake, I'm gonna drop it here in case anyone else encounters it. I didn't read the QEnv documentation all the way through. Apparently, in order to be able to run QENV on Windows you also have to run "npm install --save-dev cross-env" and modify package.json to "dev": "cross-env QENV=development quasar dev"

Comment: When you migrate/copy your quasar project, or pull from a repo, make sure '.quasar.env.json' is not an entry in your .gitignore.